# Absolutely positioned tr

Tags: html, css, html-table, position

It seems really 'hacky' to absolutely position a table row and move it around... But it works in IE7. I can't install any other browsers at the moment to test it out.

Is this a bad idea (i.e. unsupported, non-standard, etc.)?

**Edit** I'm sticking a table header in place with some frustrating requirements. So far NO PLUGINS will work for what I need to do.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: show us what you've done there))

Comment: Let's see your example, I'm sure we could find a workaround.

Comment: @Bad Display I really don't have anything concrete to show. You can see this question I asked yesterday (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511888/scrollable-table-ideas-tricky) for some clarification. Thanks!

Comment: i don't fully understand your requirements and why suggestions from that other question of yours aren't suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested this craziness in IE8, Chrome, FireFox and Safari. Works everywhere. But to answer your question: yes it's absolutely peculiar.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is a bad idea.

A `<table>` does not sound appropriate here. Use `<div>`s and `<span>`s instead of `<tr>`s and `<td>`s.

Comment: I have to use a table (see my edit). Is there any reason I shouldn't absolutely position the tr?